# How to assert equal 2 lists which contain dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

How to assert equal 2 lists which contain dicts?

```
List1 = [{'key1':'value1'}, {'key2':'value2'}, {'key3':'value3'}]
List2 = [{'key1':'value1'}, {'key2':'value2'}, {'key3':'value4'}]
```

I read that assertEqual / assertListEqual need that the list items be in the same order. Where as assertCountEqual does not consider order. This is fine if the items of the list are simple string/init value.

However, there is no clarity on whether order is important for list items also? For example - if list contains a dict or tuple item, dict is unordered so does assertEqual not check order of dict inside list? What about tuple inside list? Where can I find how this works?

Comment: Dictionaries compare equal if and only if they have the same (key, value) pairs (regardless of ordering).

Comment: That is for equality using ==. Is it the same for assertEqual?

Comment: please provide some code of what you are trying to achieve so we can help you

Comment: These dicts in your question have one item each; how could the order in the dicts matter?

Answer (score 1):

`assertEquals` simply delegates to `==`, which can be overridden by each type.

> However, there is no clarity on whether order is important for list items also?

That's because it's delegated to the list items themselves. `list.__eq__` simply checks if both lists have the same length, and if they have the same items at the same place using `==`. How `==` behaves for each item is the item's decision.

> dict is unordered so does assertEqual not check order of dict inside list?

Correct. dict equality simply checks that dicts have the same (key, value) pairs, it doesn't care about order. Same for set equality.

> What about tuple inside list?

tuple equality is the same as list equality, it does care about order.

> Where can I find how this works?

The documentation of each individual type I'd guess.